# Calculate multiple values in parallel

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, julia, distributed-computing

I have a function, `xEuclid`, for the extended euclidean algorithm, and I want to calculate 3 values using that function, being these values `a = xEuclid(a1,b1)`, `b = xEuclid(a2,b2)` and `c = xEuclid(a3,b3)`, using different parameters each call, so the idea to optimize the proces is to calculate `a`, `b` and `c` at the same time, in parallel.

I can't figure a way to solve it and unfortunately don't have the time to do the JuliaAcademy Parallel Programming tutorial, so please I need your help to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: Just for the record: common Julia style uses all-lowercase names for functions, with as few underscores as possible. `extendedeuclidean`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
using Base.Threads: @spawn
a = @spawn xEuclid(a1,b1)
b = @spawn xEuclid(a2,b2)
c = @spawn xEuclid(a3,b3)
a = fetch(a); b = fetch(b); c = fetch(c)
```

This requires at least julia v1.3

Comment: Thank you! The code works, but the sequential sum is still much faster than using spawn. The sequantial time is in the orders of nanoseconds and the parallel time is in microseconds.

Comment: That's because of the overhead of spawning threads. It makes sense to use threads only for more intensive tasks, otherwise the additional overhead kills performance

Comment: Is there another parallelization method to use in order to get much faster performance time?

Comment: Sending information to another process takes at least 1ms. You can't parallelize single operations that take too much time.

Comment: Your best bet would be to find an implementation that exploits SIMD instructions, if the algorithm lends itself well to that.